# Problemas para exibir um foreach (php) dentro de um código html

Tags: php, html

Olá, pessoal.

Estou com um pequeno problema e não consigo sair dele. O problema é o seguinte:

Estou precisando gerar um pdf (relatório) com alguns dados vindo de uma consulta mysql. Até aqui, tudo bem! Mas todo esse código que vai aparecer no pdf está sendo gerado via script PHP misturado com HTML. No meio desse código, chamo uma função e preciso exibir o resultado dela dentro de um trecho HTML, aqui que é o problema, não consigo acertar na sintaxe correta do loop foreach que está dentro desse HTML. Segue o trecho do código:

```
$montagem = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='pt-br'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>
<body>

<h1 style='font-size: 12px; text-align: center;'>ATESTADO ZOOSSANITÁRIO PARA 
CAPRINOS</h1>

<table style='width: 100%; margin: 0 20px;'>
<h1 style='font-size: 13px; text-align: center;'>IDENTIFICAÇÃO DOS ANIMAIS</h1>

<table cellspacing='0px' cellspadding='0px' style='width: 100%; margin: 0 20px;'>
<tr style='text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;'>
<td rowspan='2' style='border: 1px solid #000; border-right: 0 none; padding: 0;'>Ordem</td>
<td rowspan='2' style='border: 1px solid #000; border-right: 0 none;'>Espécie</td>
<td rowspan='2' style='border: 1px solid #000; border-right: 0 none;'>Raça</td>
<td colspan='2' style='border: 1px solid #000; border-right: 0 none; border-bottom: 0 none;'>Nº por Sexo</td>
<td rowspan='2' style='border: 1px solid #000;'>Total</td>
</tr>
<tr style='text-align: center;'>
<td style='border: 1px solid #000; border-right: 0 none;'>Macho</td>
<td style='border: 1px solid #000; border-right: 0 none;'>Fêmea</td>
</tr>
foreach ($caprinos2 as $caprino) { 
<tr class='text-center'>
<td>echo $caprinos2[capregistro]</td>
<td>$caprinos2[especie]</td>
<td>$caprinos2[raca]</td>
<td>$caprinos2[qtdmacho]</td>
<td>$caprinos2[qtdfemea]</td>
<td>$caprinos2[municipio]</td>
</tr>
}
</table>
</body>
</html>";
```

Alguém teria uma idéia de como exibir o resultado do loop foreach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP é PHP, HTML é HTML e string é string.

`Foreach` nunca vai executar dentro da **string**, você tem que concatenar, em PHP pra fazer isto use `.=` assim:

```
$foo = 'Olá ';
$foo .= 'Mundo';

echo $foo; //Vai exibir "Olá, Mundo"
```

O script deve ficar assim:

```
$montagem = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='pt-br'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>
<body>

<h1 style='font-size: 12px; text-align: center;'>ATESTADO ZOOSSANITÁRIO PARA 
CAPRINOS</h1>

<table style='width: 100%; margin: 0 20px;'>
<h1 style='font-size: 13px; text-align: center;'>IDENTIFICAÇÃO DOS ANIMAIS</h1>

<table cellspacing='0px' cellspadding='0px' style='width: 100%; margin: 0 20px;'>
<tr style='text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;'>
<td rowspan='2' style='border: 1px solid #000; border-right: 0 none; padding: 0;'>Ordem</td>
<td rowspan='2' style='border: 1px solid #000; border-right: 0 none;'>Espécie</td>
<td rowspan='2' style='border: 1px solid #000; border-right: 0 none;'>Raça</td>
<td colspan='2' style='border: 1px solid #000; border-right: 0 none; border-bottom: 0 none;'>Nº por Sexo</td>
<td rowspan='2' style='border: 1px solid #000;'>Total</td>
</tr>
<tr style='text-align: center;'>
<td style='border: 1px solid #000; border-right: 0 none;'>Macho</td>
<td style='border: 1px solid #000; border-right: 0 none;'>Fêmea</td>
</tr>";

foreach ($caprinos2 as $caprino) { 

    $montagem .= "<tr class='text-center'>
    <td>echo $caprinos2[capregistro]</td>
    <td>$caprinos2[especie]</td>
    <td>$caprinos2[raca]</td>
    <td>$caprinos2[qtdmacho]</td>
    <td>$caprinos2[qtdfemea]</td>
    <td>$caprinos2[municipio]</td>
    </tr>";

}
$montagem .= "</table>
</body>
</html>";
```

Comment: Olá, Guilherme. Obrigado pela ajuda! Mas, ao fazer os seguintes ajustes ele tá acusando o seguinte erro nas variáveis a serem exibidas: "Notice: Undefined index: capregistro in"

Comment: @VandréPaulo Esse erro não tem nada haver com os ajustes. Se vocÊ pegar o google tradutor vai saber o que significa, o problema é na tua variavel `$caprinos2` que você nem postou na pergunta, ou seja não tem nada haver com o foreach.

Comment: Verdade, Guilherme. Esse último problema era no índice da variável que usei para receber a função criada no início da arquivo, ao qual não citei no problema inicial. Já resolvi, sem a ajuda do Google Tradutor. Muito obrigado pela dica, foi de grande valia para meu problema! Um forte abraço!